# How can I set the size of this GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have an applet (and this is an SSCCE):

```
package tutoringcalculator;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TutoringCalculator extends JApplet {
    private JPanel _root;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tutoring Calculator");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JApplet applet = new TutoringCalculator();
                applet.init();

                frame.setContentPane(applet.getContentPane());

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                applet.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private JPanel swingContainer;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        swingContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(swingContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        createScene();
        setSize(600, 400);
    }

    private void createScene() {
        JLabel lbl;
        JTextField txt;

        _root = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        // build the session minutes
        lbl = new JLabel();
        lbl.setText("Session Minutes:");
        _root.add(lbl);

        txt = new JTextField();
        _root.add(txt);

        swingContainer.add(_root);
    }
}
```

and I'd like to set the size to 600x400 - but I've issued `setSize(600, 400)` on `applet`, `frame`, `swingContainer`, and `_root` and nothing changes. I get a screen that looks like this:

[image: Tutoring Calculator Window]

Comment: An applet's height is typically set in the HTML.  Since your case is 'atypical', I'll have to look more closely at it..

Comment: Applets get there size of the html tag

Comment: `pack` wants to use the `preferredSize` of the content pane (once all the components have been laid out).  In this case, you may need to set the applet's content pane's preferred size manually within the frame generation code.  This is one of the (many) reasons why you should never add controls directly to a top level container and instead use some kind of container (like a `JPanel`) which can be added/transplanted as needed - IMHO

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I'll be honest, I'm really confused about what I am using and what I'm not using. I do now more clearly see that the namespace is `javax.swing` rather than `javafx.swing`. Sorry.

Comment: *"and this is an SSCCE"*  Oh yes, & +1 for that.  Makes it so easy to work with.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, an applet typically gets a size (forced upon it) by the HTML.  A free floating `JFrame` is different.  Instead it has components inside which suggest a size, which is then calculated at time of `pack()`.  E.G. after setting a size in the constructor of the `JTextField`, this is what we see:

[image: Small Tutoring Calculator]

Now, I expect you are going to be adding a whole lot more components to this before it's done, and they will make the size bigger as well, but there are also some other tips for making the content larger.  Borders & layout padding.  Here is what it looks like with some of that.

[image: Tutoring Calculator with white space]

So, what it comes down to is either a) Add a whole bunch of components that will make a GUI bigger, and/or b) add white space as defined in the layout constructors & borders.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TutoringCalculator {

    private JPanel _root;
    private JPanel swingContainer;
    private JLabel lbl;
    private JTextField txt;

    TutoringCalculator() {
        swingContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        // set an empty border to it
        swingContainer.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));

        // suggest a spacing of 20px between components
        _root = new JPanel(new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.CENTER, 20, 20));
        swingContainer.add(_root);

        // add a line border so we can see the bounds of this container
        _root.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

        // this has a size as needed by the content
        lbl = new JLabel("Session Minutes:");
        _root.add(lbl);

        // Suggest a size (in characters - 10) for the text field
        txt = new JTextField(10);
        _root.add(txt);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tutoring Calculator");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                TutoringCalculator calc = new TutoringCalculator();

                frame.setContentPane(calc.swingContainer);

                frame.pack();
                // much better!
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that I've also removed the (now) entirely redundant applet.