# How set location of an image in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I'm trying to set the the location of an image in a JFrame.  I thought **label.setLocation(100, 100);** would set the location of the image to 100, 100 (top left corner), but it doesn't seem to do anything no matter were I put it.  I even tried panal.setLocation(100, 100).  Both do nothing, I get **no errors** and the **image does appears** but at 0, 0.  What am I doning wrong?  Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;  

public class DisplayImage {  
    public DisplayImage() {  
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Image");  
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

        JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();  

        JLabel label = new JLabel();  
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/img/school.png"));
        label.setLocation(100, 100);
        panel.add(label);  

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
        frame.pack();  
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }  

    public static void main (String args[]) {  
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {  
                new DisplayImage();  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space, to organize the components.

Comment: ..See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16582851/418556) for a demo.

Answer (score 4):

By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout. When you add your label to the frame the label is added to the CENTER of the BorderLayout. The layout manager will override the location.

One simple solution is to add an EmptyBorder to the label with the top/left insets being 100. Then instead of add the label to the center you would add the label to the NORTH. The code would be something like:

```
label.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(...) );
panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

As a general rule you should not be trying to specify exact location of a component. Let the layout managers to their jobs.

Comment: Well I really want a background image and then layer other images on top of the background

Comment: @Java That information would have been useful as part of the question.  Try taking a look at [How to use layered panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) or create a custom pane/layout manager...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think I found a less complicated solution to my problem

Answer (score 3):

The `JFrame`, by default, uses a `BorderLayout` as it's layout manager.  This will override any settings you supply to the `setLocation` method.

You have a number of options...

- Use something like `JLayeredPane`, which does not, but default, have layout manager of it's own set by default. See [How to use layered panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more details
- Create a custom component capable of renderering the image where you want it.  Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details
- Create your own layout manager that performs the operations you want...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;  

public class DisplayImage {  
    public DisplayImage() {  
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Image");  
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

        JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();  
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();  
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("rails.png"));
        panel.add(label);
        Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
        label.setBounds(100, 100, size.width, size.height);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);  
    }  

    public static void main (String args[]) {  
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {  
                new DisplayImage();  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

But you should read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: `null` layout is never a suitable suggestion.  The problem is there is a lot of management code surrounding the updating of the containers, including things like `preferred/minimum/maximum/Size` that allows other layout managers to make decisions about how best to respond to changes in the environment.  You may also find that different platforms have different DPIs and font metrics which will effect how these components are laid out - IMHO

Comment: *"This works for me:"*   `setLayout(null);` Why just develop for you?  This will probably break on the next machine, PLAF, .. -1

Comment: I never advocated doing that, and my link advising against it was to the wrong page.  Bu Sun does say: "Creating a container without a layout manager involves the following steps.

Set the container's layout manager to null by calling setLayout(null)."

Comment: *"I never advocated doing that"* The words *"This works for me:"* read to me like you are advocating it.  Maybe it is just me.  Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify them of a new comment.

Comment: The reason we kind of "jump" on `null` layouts is that the next question the OP will ask is "why does not container not show up", which the answer is, `null` layout...it's a vicious circle which is just best avoided while people are learning Swing...IMHO

Comment: "This works for me:" is taken out of context.  My post says: 
"This works for me ..... But you should read this..."  And now the link correctly points to the warnings about doing that, rather than a link to the code example.  In addition, the qualification "this works for me" connotates "It might not work for you".  It is not the same as saying, "You need to do this..."  "This works for me" is a well known mea culpa in computer programming forums.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, "it's a vicious circle which is just best avoided while people are learning Swing...IMHO".  Yes, I agree.  Swing is a quagmire.